# Button action inside custom function in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I don't want to use the same piece of code in every UIViewController swift file, so I created a custom function:

```
import Foundation;
import UIKit;

func noSignal(view : UIView) -> UIView {

    let noConnectionView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 260, 200));
    noConnectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    noConnectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    noConnectionView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
    noConnectionView.layer.shadowRadius = 8;
    noConnectionView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    noConnectionView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    noConnectionView.center = view.center;

    let heading = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10,40,240,20));
    heading.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
    heading.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    heading.text = "NO CONNECTION";
    noConnectionView.addSubview(heading);

    let message = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(10,80,240,60));
    message.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
    message.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;
    message.text = "Please enable internet connection in your device (WiFi or Mobile) and tap retry.";
    noConnectionView.addSubview(message);

    let retry = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(60,140,140,40));
    retry.setTitle("Retry", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
    retry.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
    retry.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xF91A6E);
    retry.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal);
    retry.addTarget(self, action: "retryConnection:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);

    noConnectionView.addSubview(retry);
    view.addSubview(noConnectionView);


    return noConnectionView;

}
```

In all examples I've seen addTarget should refer to self, but when I do this Xcode shows use uf unresolved identifier 'self', so I've tried to use view then it compiles. But when I tap retry button it crashes.

So my question is, where should I place "retryConnection" function, should be inside noSignal function, or somewhere else? This function is run within UIWebView webViewDidStartLoad.

Comment: inside the same class where your `noSignal` func is.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with that pass viewcontroller on which you are adding that view and change target to that viewcontroller instead of self

```
    func noSignal(view : UIView , viewController : UIViewController) -> UIView {

    let noConnectionView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(100, 200, 260, 200));
    noConnectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    noConnectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    noConnectionView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor;
    noConnectionView.layer.shadowRadius = 8;
    noConnectionView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    noConnectionView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    noConnectionView.center = view.center;

    let heading = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(10,40,240,20));
    heading.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
    heading.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    heading.text = "NO CONNECTION";
    noConnectionView.addSubview(heading);

    let message = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(10,80,240,60));
    message.textColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor();
    message.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left;
    message.text = "Please enable internet connection in your device (WiFi or Mobile) and tap retry.";
    noConnectionView.addSubview(message);

    let retry = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(60,140,140,40));
    retry.setTitle("Retry", forState: UIControlState.Normal);
    retry.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
 //   retry.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xF91A6E);
    retry.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal);
    retry.addTarget(viewController, action: "retryConnection:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);

    noConnectionView.addSubview(retry);
    view.addSubview(noConnectionView);


    return noConnectionView;

}
```

Comment: I did this. However where should I place retryConnection function? I've tried that within that function and in view controller, but when I tap the button, it throws: unrecognized selector sent to instance error

Comment: you have to put retryconnection in that viewcontrollr which you are passing in method

Comment: Unfortunately It throws the same error no matter where I place it. Now I've tried to initialize noSignal function in viewDidLoad but nothing helps. The message pops perfectly but tapping that button still crashes my app.

Comment: It worked, all I had to do was to remove colon in action:"retryConnection"